# iptables dos limit for all ports

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables, conntrack

I know how to use limit conntrack option to allow for DoS protection. However, I want to add a protection to limit no more than say 50 connections for each port. How can I do this?

Basically, I want to make sure that **each port can have no more than 50 connections**, rather than globally applying 50 connections (which is what #2 does I believe?)

Would I do something like:

```
iptables -A INPUT --dport 1:65535 -m limit --limit 50/minute --limit-burst 50 -j ACCEPT
```

or

```
iptables -A INPUT -m limit --limit 50/minute --limit-burst 50 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: but you do know that this will limit both rouge and valid connections without distinguishing between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be looking at the `--hitcount` switch.

> --hitcount [hits]
>
> match requiring a certain number of hits within a specific time frame.
>   The maximum value for the hitcount parameter is  given  by  the 
>   "ip_pkt_list_tot"

You will also be interested in the `--seconds` switch.

I believe a sample rule using port 80 and restricting connections to 50 per hour would be something like this:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 3600 --hitcount 50 -j DROP
```

Comment: @user973917 Oops, sorry. I'm pretty sure that would limit the entire range, not each port within the range. =/